# Magmi Import SQL import, works on local server

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magmi, magento-1.8

I have been using Magmi for a long time, and had issues with it so far, but now I'm trying to do a CSV import with Magmi, and for some reason it throws this SQL error, and have no idea how to fix it.

- Magento: 1.8.1.0
- PHP: 5.3.3-7+squeeze18
- MySQL: 5.1.73
- MySQLi: 5.1.73

**The error:**

```
1 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1 - DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_tier_price WHERE entity_id=? AND customer_group_id IN (?) AND website_id IN ()
2 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1 - ERROR ON RECORD #1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem!

When I use `category_ids` like: `4,35,5` it gives me the error.

But! If I just use a single number, no error!

Answer (score 2):

MAGMI is a fantastic piece of software. I have great admiration for the coder who created it.

I don't know for sure but I think the issue is to do with the `websites` column or lack of it.

Re-read some of the info here about specifying `website`: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Tier_price_importer

When I use MAGMI for csv import I have a `website` column but I set it to _MAGMI_IGNORE_ but for your example I think you might need to list the website codes explicitly - worth a try I think and this issue may be related to Magento 1.8

Comment: Bummer. Well, you know, MAGMI is just PHP so you could sprinkle it with some var_dump() and echo() but I'm pretty sure you need something inside the empty parentheses of `website_id IN ()`.